# Passing props to the page component in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs a withlayout function to add a sidebar for certain pages.

```
export type PageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  withLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};
```

Here is how I use it:

```
export const Interactions: PageWithLayout = () => {
  const [
    getInteractions,
    {
      data: interactionData,
      fetchMore,
      variables,
      loading: isInteractionsLoading,
      error: isInteractionsError,
    },
  ] = useGetInteractionsLazyQuery({
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    ssr: false,
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Box height={"100vh"}>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

Interactions.withLayout = (page: ReactElement) => {
// how do I pass isInteractionsLoading as a prop to this component
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};

export default Interactions;
```

What I would like to achieve is pass the isInteractionsLoaded and isInteractionsError as a propr to my Layout component so I can render these states. Is there a way to achieve this without having to move my layout component inside the page component?

Comment: Why are you using `withLayout` instead of putting the `<Layout>` wrapper inside the component?

Comment: Cleaner code preference and to seperate things

Comment: Well you can't really separate things in this case, now can you?

Comment: well that was my question if there was a way to approach this

Comment: Create a Context: Define a context that will hold the states you want to share.

Create a Context Provider: Wrap your page component in a context provider and pass the states as the context value.

Consume the Context in the Layout: Access the context in your Layout component to get the states.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a [React Context](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) provider that wraps your  component could be a solution you use could use if you wanted to not use any additional packages or not reach for more powerful tools like redux.

---

Example context and usage

```
import React from 'react';

export const InteractionContext = React.createContext({
  isInteractionsLoading: false,
  isInteractionsError: null,
});

// parent component or _app if necessary

const ProviderComponent = () => {
  return (
    <InteractionContext.Provider value={{ isInteractionsLoading, isInteractionsError }}>
      <Interactions />
    </InteractionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const { isInteractionsLoading, isInteractionsError } = useContext(InteractionContext);

  // Now you can use isInteractionsLoading and isInteractionsError here
  // ...

  return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export a `getServerSideProps` function for server side rendered pages or a or a `getStaticProps` function for static pages.

In each of these functions, you can return an object with a props key.
The props returned in the function(s) can then be access in the page component itself.

For instance if you have a component like , where you want two props, name and data, you do something like this:

```js
export default function MyComponent ({ data, name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Example Page {name}</h1>
      <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps ({ params,locale }) {
  // Fetch data from an API or any other source
  const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props {
    data,
    name : "A Name"
  }
}
```

You can do the same for `getStaticProps`, just that the it executed only once (when the page is being rendered)

> The `getStaticProps` function should return an object containing either
> props, redirect, or notFound followed by an optional revalidate
> property.

See here https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-static-props